# can't get the first nested order list html

Tags: html, css

So I've tried looking for the answers on this website and Google. I swear I have the right idea to "close" off each ordered list accordingly:

```css
ol {list-style-type: upper-roman; }
ol ol {list-style-type: upper-alpha;}
ol ol ol {list-style-type: decimal;}
div.pro {background-color: pink;}
div.pale {color: white; background-color: blue;}
div.meso {background-color: green;}
div.ceno {color: white; background-color: red;}
```

```html
<h2><u>The following are different eras to mark</u></h2>

<div class="pro"> 

<ol>
    <li> Proterozoic:

        <ol>
         <li>None</li>

        </ol>
    </li>
    
</div>

<div class="pale">
<ol>    
    <li> Paleozoic:
        <ol>
         <li> Cambrian</li>
         <li> Ordovician</li>
         <li> Silurian</li>
         <li> Devonian</li>
         <li> Mississippian</li>
         <li> Pennsylvanian</li>
         <li> Permian</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    

</div>

<div class="meso">
<ol>
    <li> Mesozoic: 
        <ol>
         <li> Triassic</li>
         <li> Jurassic</li>
         <li> Cretaceous</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    
</div>


<div class="ceno">
<ol>
    <li> Cenozoic:

        <ol>
         <li> Paleogene:
            <ol>
             <li> Paleocene</li>
             <li> Eocene</li>
             <li> Oligocene</li>
         </li>
            </ol>
    
         <li> Neogene:
            <ol>
             <li> Miocene</li>
             <li> Pliocene</li>
             <li> Pleistocene</li>
             <li> Holocene</li>
         
            </ol>
         </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</div>
</ol>
```

Which it comes out like this:

[image]

**As** you can see, everything looks good BUT the first ordered list with the roman numerals. I've tried to "close" out respectfully with "li" or "ol" where I thought needed, but then it completely garbles everything up into their own lists, etc.

Just need another pair of eyes to explain/see where I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The first ordered list is Proterozoic and looks same as the other. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: objective was to nest list different eras with background colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code editor suggest there were elements that does not have closing tags, it cause a confusion to the browser on how exactly to render your element. Maybe your putting a closing tag to it but was put on a wrong spot in attempt to achieve some styling effect.

see the screenshot:

[image: element with out closing tag]

Here is the code that was modified from the original version of your code. It renders correctly the ordered list is annotated correctly and it has the same styling effect as yours.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fashion Closet</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style type="text/css">
    ol {
      list-style-type: upper-roman;
      list-style-position: inside;
    }

    ol ol {
      list-style-type: upper-alpha;
    }

    ol ol ol {
      list-style-type: decimal;
    }

    .pro {
      background-color: pink;
    }

    .pale {
      color: white;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .meso {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .ceno {
      color: white;
      background-color: red;
    }

    body>ol li {
      margin: 1em 0;
      padding-left: 2em;
    }

    body>ol {
      margin: 0 2em 0 0;
    }

    body>h2 {
      margin-left: 2em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2><u>The following are different eras to mark</u></h2>
  <ol>
    <li class="pro">
      Proterozoic:
      <ol>
        <li>None</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="pale">
      Paleozoic:
      <ol>
        <li> Cambrian</li>
        <li> Ordovician</li>
        <li> Silurian</li>
        <li> Devonian</li>
        <li> Mississippian</li>
        <li> Pennsylvanian</li>
        <li> Permian</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="meso">
      Mesozoic:
      <ol>
        <li> Triassic</li>
        <li> Jurassic</li>
        <li> Cretaceous</li>
      </ol>

    </li>
    <li class="ceno">
      Cenozoic:
      <ol>
        <li>
          Paleogene:
          <ol>
            <li> Paleocene</li>
            <li> Eocene</li>
            <li> Oligocene</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
          Neogene:
          <ol>
            <li> Miocene</li>
            <li> Pliocene</li>
            <li> Pleistocene</li>
            <li> Holocene</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this one worked out great! but do i need to add the body/margin stuff?? i appreciate your help. i figured i may have missed a closed somewhere but i couldnt figure out where, or maybe i was putting too many. thank you!

also what editor is your screenshot? cause notepad++ didnt give me errors or anything, unless i have settings wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below updated code. I have reorder your ol and li outside div.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            ol {list-style-type: upper-roman; }
            ol ol {list-style-type: upper-alpha;}
            ol ol ol {list-style-type: decimal;}
            div.pro {background-color: pink;}
            div.pale {color: white; background-color: blue;}
            div.meso {background-color: green;}
            div.ceno {color: white; background-color: red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2><u>The following are different eras to mark</u></h2>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <div class="pro">
                    Proterozoic:
                    <ol>
                        <li>None</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="pale">
                    Paleozoic:
                    <ol>
                        <li> Cambrian</li>
                        <li> Ordovician</li>
                        <li> Silurian</li>
                        <li> Devonian</li>
                        <li> Mississippian</li>
                        <li> Pennsylvanian</li>
                        <li> Permian</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="meso">
                    Mesozoic: 
                    <ol>
                        <li> Triassic</li>
                        <li> Jurassic</li>
                        <li> Cretaceous</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="ceno">
                    Cenozoic:
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            Paleogene:
                            <ol>
                                <li> Paleocene</li>
                                <li> Eocene</li>
                                <li> Oligocene</li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Neogene:
                            <ol>
                                <li> Miocene</li>
                                <li> Pliocene</li>
                                <li> Pleistocene</li>
                                <li> Holocene</li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was great! so i just had my li, ol and divs mixed around?? Only problem was, the roman numerals were outside the colors.